# Unable to connect database on QT

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I keep receiving this error whenever I try connecting my database on QT.

The error message states:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I've tried adding the "libmysql.dll" to the Qt binaries however, the error persists.

Please may I receive some help on this.

Comment: You have to compile the Qt MySQL plugin by yourself since Qt is not allowed to provide a binary plugin for MySQL to to legal reasons of the mysql lib. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers) for a tutorial on how to build the plugin.

Comment: @chehrlic thanks for the recommendation, I'll try it and get back to you